# Phonegap open external links outside App from a Whitelist URL

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using Phonegap 2.3 and I'm considering updating to the newer library.  I think this might be a problem that was fixed with the newer library.

Anyway I have tried:

```
window.open('http://google.com','_blank')

window.location = "http://google.com";
```

Both had no luck forcing the user to load the external link in safari.

I also ready about targeting `_system` which didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a config.xml setting that will do the trick:

`<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />`

Or, you can use _system if you include the InAppBrowser plugin.

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.nhl.com', '_system', 'location=yes');">_system</a>`

[InAppBrowser API Doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Here's a couple related threads:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml (page search for "stay-in-webview")

[PhoneGap Build: how to open external url in device browser on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534630/phonegap-build-how-to-open-external-url-in-device-browser-on-android)

Comment: Thanks I just need to find the config.xml

Comment: No problem. This should point you in the right direction. Now, how about an upvote and marking the answer as correct? ;) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_project-settings_index.md.html

Comment: Where does it say that the `_system` has been deprecated?

Comment: Looks like it isn't. The "ChildBrowser" plugin is now deprecated and the functionality has now been moved to the InAppBrowser API. I will edit my answer accordingly. http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_childbrowser_plugin_deprecating_use_inappbrowser

Answer (score 1):

For Phonegap 3 you have to install the [InAppBrowser plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) and then do:

```
window.open("http://google.com", "_system");
```