# Phonegap: Open a URL in default browser

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

How to open a URL in default browser in android?

I've tried `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');">www.google.com</a>` but it opens up in the same app window, but I want it to open up in a default browser's window.

Comment: for me it is open my default browser only..i just copy paste your above code..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534630/phonegap-build-how-to-open-external-url-in-device-browser-on-android

Comment: oh is it! Which device are you using? ... I have tested this in Nexus 4 and the AVD or android emulator and this is what happens.

Comment: nexus 7 and also emulator. May be if you are using phonegap build you got like above...

Comment: Oh now I got what I missed :) ... I had missed to add `<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />` in my plugin.xml. Thanks for sharing the link @Aravin. :) If you can post it as an answer I can mark this as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you added the in app browser plugin. Please check it in your config.xml file(It is in your `res/xml/config.xml`) the following line is present.

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

Like the following you can add the plugin:

```
phonegap local plugin add your plugin url here
```

And also chances may be there if you are using **phonegap build** the in app browser is open instead of default system browser(even though you are using `_system`).

For more details refer this [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534630/phonegap-build-how-to-open-external-url-in-device-browser-on-android)

Comment: Thanks, I am using AngularJS and PhoneGap to make this app but the click does not open up the web page not even inside the app or in the default web browser. But when i use this without angularjs it works. any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Thats OK Aravin. Anyways your solution worked for the normal HTML, JS, Phonegap solution :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to install inappbrowser plugin in your app like this

cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

after successful install the above code will start working.